# Dynamic tab in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

i have 2 tabs in my project one is movies and other one is songs

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-koal1q

my problem is when i switch between tabs then tab is not Maintaining  it's previous status , my code is creating tabs with close button,when i click on tab then it's redirecting content of tab  , but i want to maintain individual container for each tab ,how to achieve in angular

Answer (score 0):

**menu.component.html**

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu-options-list">
    <li *ngFor="let option of menuOptions" class="menu-option"  [routerLink]="option.url" routerLinkActive="active">
      {{option.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**menu.component.css**

```
.active {
   background-color: #7a9d96;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is working Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y39htm

Comment: sorry small correction , i want multiple tabs with individual container ,,when i write something in tab movies should hold when i come back from songs tab to movies tab ,(should not empty when i swap from one tab to other tab )

Comment: I Hope, this is helpful!